# Providing border-collapse to collapse affects overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I am creating the group button using `ul` `li`. In order to float the `li` in ul, i have set `display:table` value to `ul` and `display:table-cell` to `li` elements. `Li` elements has span and div nodes which is used to append the text/icon with In this.

This works fine.

But if I set `border-collapse:collapse` to table, `width:100%` concept not works as expected. If i give more text in a span (inside `li`), `li` width gets increased instead of wrapping into given space. I have set `width:100%` to `ul` where its parent div has `300px`. Tried by setting overflow hidden but no use

This overflow problem gets resolved if I set to `border-collapse:separate` but I don't want double thick border(for each border 1px) with my `li` elements. 
So please provide any solution to wrap the text inside `li`, even if I provide more content with `border-collapse:collapse`. Else suggest any option to with `border-collapse:separate` with no double border.

Here is my plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/th0ylX4dccZmoSeURk77?p=preview

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a plunker or a code snippet?

Comment: use `table-layout:fixed` in css for table

Comment: can you please add your code or jsfiddle link?

Comment: Try to use `display: inline-block` for `li` or `flex` for `ul` instead of `display: table`.

Comment: Hi All,  here is plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/th0ylX4dccZmoSeURk77?p=preview

Comment: @SasiDhivya Do you wants all `li` having same width?

Comment: @muhammad no its need to auto correct based on content

Comment: overflow hidden should be applied to .cells_li div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would better to use flex for your task.
Add `display: flex` to container and `flex: 1 1 auto` to `li` elements. `flex: 1 1 auto` means that this element takes all available space.

Another example: http://jsfiddle.net/w23nuqvx/.

```css
.table_ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
  
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
     -ms-flex-pack: start;
   justify-content: flex-start;
  
  width: 300px;
  
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;  
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* flex-wrap: nowrap; disabling wrapping*/
  
  list-style: none;
}

.cells_li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
              flex: 1 1 auto;
  
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.cells_li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="group" class="main_div">
  <ul class="table_ul">
    <li class="cells_li"><div><span>fghjkjhgfdsdfghj</span></div></li>
    <li class="cells_li"><div><span>Desktop</span></div></li>
    <li class="cells_li"><div><span>DeskTop</span></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi looks fine Thanks for effort. I will try this and let u know since i have to test in more cases i need some time. But its seems as good idea

Comment: I have used your code and edited based on my issue. Can you please check on this. Here i have to adjust ul li based on parent div changes. height and width of the parent div will be change dynamically in code behind. All the inner elements should adjust based on parent changes. The text content should always be center. Is there any option? Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: @SasiDhivya I made a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/w23nuqvx/ Does it solve your issure?

Comment: yes its looking fine and working thank you very much. Also flex is the best option for this type ul li structure. you saved my time